# Android - Recyclerview does not Update Item Info

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am developing a chat application. When you enter the chat, you set all the received messages as seen. But in the other device if I am in the chat too, the boolean "seen" of each message does not update. I mean when a send message is seen, a textview "seen" appears. But I have to go out and return to the chat activity to see that textview.

Here is the onBindViewHolder void:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.isRecyclable();

    Messages messages = userMessages.get(position);

    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
    String from_user_id = messages.getSender();

    holder.seenView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(user_id.equals(from_user_id)){
        //I send the message
        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_message_bg);
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.msgParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(holder.msgParams);
        holder.dateParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageDate.setLayoutParams(holder.dateParams);
        holder.params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        if(messages.isSeen() && position == getItemCount() - 1){
            holder.seenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        //I receive the message
        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_message_bg_2);
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.msgParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(holder.msgParams);
        holder.dateParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageDate.setLayoutParams(holder.dateParams);
        holder.params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        mDatabase.child(user_id).child(from_user_id).child("messages").child(messages.getId()).child("seen").setValue(true);
        mDatabase.child(from_user_id).child(user_id).child("messages").child(messages.getId()).child("seen").setValue(true);
    }

    holder.getAdapterPosition();

    //Poner texto
    holder.messageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    holder.messageDate.setText(messages.getTime());
}
```

My loadMessages void:

```
private void loadMessages() {

    mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUser).child(userKey).child("messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);

            messagesList.add(messages);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

I tried to put a "refresh" in onChildChanged but it just add an item copy of the message...

i am looking forward to hearing from you!

**EDIT: My entire adapter:**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

private List<Messages> userMessages;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> userMessages) {
    this.userMessages = userMessages;
}

public void setData(List<Messages> newData) {
    this.userMessages.clear();
    userMessages.addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages");

    return new MessageViewHolder(V);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.isRecyclable();

    Messages messages = userMessages.get(position);

    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
    String from_user_id = messages.getSender();

    holder.seenView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(user_id.equals(from_user_id)){
        //Yo envié el mensaje
        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_message_bg);
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.msgParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(holder.msgParams);
        holder.dateParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageDate.setLayoutParams(holder.dateParams);
        holder.params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        if(messages.isSeen() && position == getItemCount() - 1){
            holder.seenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        //Recivo el mensaje
        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_message_bg_2);
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.msgParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(holder.msgParams);
        holder.dateParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.messageDate.setLayoutParams(holder.dateParams);
        holder.params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        mDatabase.child(user_id).child(from_user_id).child("messages").child(messages.getId()).child("seen").setValue(true);
        mDatabase.child(from_user_id).child(user_id).child("messages").child(messages.getId()).child("seen").setValue(true);
    }

    holder.getAdapterPosition();

    //Poner texto
    holder.messageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    holder.messageDate.setText(messages.getTime());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userMessages.size();
}

public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView messageText;
    public TextView messageDate;
    public TextView seenView;
    public LinearLayout layout;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams dateParams;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams msgParams;

    public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        messageDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        seenView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.visto);
        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageSingleLayout);
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
        dateParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        msgParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show your code that used for setup adapter with recyclerview

Comment: There I put the entire adapter!

Comment: I think you should go for implementation using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter so that any change in child data will get handled without any extra efforts. I had same issues while implementation and I opted for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and my chat app is working smoothly now.

Comment: Only the change in adapter will be needed if you go for it.

Comment: Add ELSE condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have only handled the event for New message added, if it's updated seen you have to handle that event

```
mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUser).child(userKey).child("messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
             @Override
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

     Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);

     messagesList.add(messages);
     messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);

 }

 @Override
 public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
             Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
             int i=0;
             boolean isMatch=false;
            for(Messages m:messagesList)
            {
                if(messages.getId()==m.getId())
                {
                isMatch=true;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }

            if(isMatch)
            messagesList.set(i,messages);
            else
            messagesList.add(messages);
             messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that new code but the problem persist... And if I put `messagesList.add(messages);` a new copy is added

Comment: you have to identify it must update based on some unique value that your `Messages` contain, is there any unique key or id?

Comment: The message is stored in the DataBase with an unique id. Here it is called `messages.getId()`

Comment: identify the position of message in `messagesList` there is have the same message and replace it with updated message

Comment: I am sorry, how can I identify the position?

Comment: I finally fixed it! I tried your code but did not work. Then I tried to remove the last message with `messagesList.remove(messagesList.size()-1);`  and `messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` so I can re-add the message!

Comment: that's not solution suppose at time two more message get updated what is output?

Comment: @NicolasVillar have you debug? why it not working if your id is `string` you have to use.`equal` instant of `==`